# How to link data between two UITableViews?

Tags: objective-c, json

I got some trouble and I need some help, here it is:
on my project, I built taxi system and each taxi service shown as pin in mapView. each pin has annotation show the name and number of those services. The data is parsed from JSON. On the annotationView, I also have right call out button to view information of every single service. It means that from the annotationView, I put the button and it moves to another view. So how can I do that? the code bellow shows how to get the data from JSON, but in right call out button, how the taxi service info shown in the next view? For example, this annotation view shows ABC taxi service, and in the callout button, it shows the information of that service. The information already parsed from JSON.

```
for (NSMutableArray *stationDictionary in stationData) {
    station.name = [stationDictionary objectAtIndex:10];
    station.number = [stationDictionary objectAtIndex:11];
    station.info = [stationDictionary objectAtIndex:12];
}
```

I hope you get my point and I really appreciate your helps. Thanks.

Comment: use the titles and isEqualToString Property for titles comparision

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap up the information you wish to display in a class, you can pass those objects around (or arrays of multiple objects) from view to view. For instance, in a medical app I've written, when I go from a list of surgical cases to detail about a particular surgical case, I have a list of cases in the first view (which controls what info is displayed there). When the user taps on a particular case to view details, I load the next view (which contains more detail about a particular case) and pass the selected case to the new view.

So, you need to lay out a data structure that makes sense of what you have (taxis, services, phone numbers, etc...). Then, parse the JSON into a list of objects. After that, it's a fairly straightforward matter of deciding what info to display on which views at a certain time.